# Can a chameleon with Arcane Focus prepare Read Magic from memory?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, chameleon

The chameleon's Arcane Focus option states the following:

> Arcane Focus: You gain the ability to prepare and cast arcane spells,
>   which may be chosen from the spell list of any arcane spellcasting
>   class. **You prepare and cast these spells just as a wizard does,
>   including the use of a spellbook**

Emphasis mine. Here is a rule for wizards and the use of a spellbook:

> Spellbooks
>
> A wizard must study her spellbook each day to prepare her spells. She
>   cannot prepare any spell not recorded in her spellbook, except for
>   read magic, which all wizards can prepare from memory.

My question is whether a chameleon is able to prepare Read Magic from memory the way a wizard does. Essentially, does a chameleon with Arcane Focus follow *all* rules about wizards preparing spells (except when chameleon specifies otherwise) due to the use of "just as," or is the second quote somehow separate from that, applying only to actual members of the wizard class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Chameleons (with that focus option) can prepare Read Magic from memory.  Any time the rules state "just as X", it means that the ability functions *identically* to X, even counting as X for the purpose of other abilities, except for any alterations, omissions, and/or additions specified in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Chameleons get to prepare Read Magic from memory just as wizards do. They have memorized everything they would need to prepare Read Magic, but it is just as much a part of Arcane Focus as the proper way to hold a sword is mixed into their Combat Focus. For a fighter that kind of thing is just as ingrained as a wizard's ability to prepare Read Magic without needing it written down; chameleons have to figuratively switch a lot of mental gears to go from Combat Focus to Arcane Focus.

Answer (score -3):

In cases like this I have found that it is better to err on the side of simplicity for the sake of player fun. It's true that many of us enjoy discussing rules and trying to figure out unique things we can do within the frame work of the rules but as the DM Guide has always said in every edition, rules must take a back seat to fun.

In a situation where the rules are breaking the fun of the players it's your responsibility as a DM to break or change those rules. Exercise your DM's discretion in this case and decide which would be more fun for your player.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This question is tagged rules as written, which should be unnecessary given that it's a basic rules clarification question, but your answer has proven the OP's wisdom in attempting to forestall non-answer answers not addressing the rules.  Please take the time to read through our help center so as to be better prepared to answer questions in the future.  Hope to see you around!